# Why has the Higgs potential the form it has?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, potential, higgs

The potential for the Higgs field is a quartic one (Mexican hat). Is this done for simplicity or are there fundamental reasons for this choice? I can imagine further contributions to this potential without altering the essentials, which may lead to differences in the derived particle masses.

Comment: I always thought is was more "urban sombrero" shaped.

Answer (score 4):

In four dimensions, the quartic is the worst interaction between scalar fields that is renormalizable (by power counting arguments).

Cubics would also do but only in combination with quartics as a pure cubic potential is not bounded below. A further discrete symmetry assumption (e.g. symmetry under $\phi \mapsto -\phi$) rules out the cubic term.

Comment: Weak SU(2) charge conservation rules out the cubic term--- the Higgs doublet can't make a cubic term which is gauge invariant.

Comment: Regarding the first sentence, you'd have to say in $d=4$.

Comment: @JamalS: I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by worst?

Comment: It means that it is the higher power that works : $\phi^{5}$ would not be renormalizable

Comment: @Jiminion Since $[\phi] = 1$, $[\phi^5]$ would have dimensions of $5$, but for the action to be dimensionless, that means there is a coupling $[\lambda] = -1$, which is not renormalizable.